# I implemented queue using template to use with my custom data type but I am getting error

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, data-structures

I implemented queue and made a custom data type "coordinates" (I want to store x and y as a pair but I dont want to use pair provided is STL (for learning purposes))

But in the queue.front() implementation I am getting the error

CODE:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>

class node{
    public:
    T value;
    node <T> *next;
    node(T x)
    {
        value = x;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

template <class T>
class queue{
    node<T> *start;
    node<T> *end;

    public:

    queue()
    {
        start = NULL;
        end = NULL;
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        return start == NULL;
    }

    void push(T v)
    {
        node<T> *temp = new node<T>(v);
        if(empty())
        {
            start = temp;
            end = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            end->next = temp;
            end = temp;
        }
        return;
    }

    void pop()
    {
        if(empty())
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            node<T> *temp = start;
            start = start->next;
            delete temp;
        }
        return;
    }

    T front()
    {
        if(empty())
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            return start->value;
        }
    }

};

class coordinate
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    coordinate(int a,int b)
    {
        this->x = a;
        this->y = b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    coordinate p =coordinate(1,2);
    cout<<p.x;                              // getting expected output of 1
    pair a = make_pair(1,2);
    queue<coordinate> q;
    q.push(coordinate(1,2));
    cout<<q.front().x;
    return 0;   
}
```

ERROR:

```
In file included from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/stddef.h:1,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdint.h:32,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/stdint.h:9,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/cstdint:41,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:501,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ios:40,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from E:\Coding\CP\solid-octo-engine\DataStructures and Algorithms\Queue\QueueImplementationUsingLL.cpp:1:
E:\Coding\CP\solid-octo-engine\DataStructures and Algorithms\Queue\QueueImplementationUsingLL.cpp: In instantiation of 'T queue<T>::front() [with T = coordinate]':
E:\Coding\CP\solid-octo-engine\DataStructures and Algorithms\Queue\QueueImplementationUsingLL.cpp:102:16:   required from here
E:\Coding\CP\solid-octo-engine\DataStructures and Algorithms\Queue\QueueImplementationUsingLL.cpp:73:11: error: could not convert '0' from 'long long int' to 'coordinate'
    return NULL;
           ^~~~
E:\Coding\CP\solid-octo-engine\DataStructures and Algorithms\Queue\QueueImplementationUsingLL.cpp: In instantiation of 'node<T>::node(T) [with T = coordinate]':
E:\Coding\CP\solid-octo-engine\DataStructures and Algorithms\Queue\QueueImplementationUsingLL.cpp:40:19:   required from 'void queue<T>::push(T) [with T = coordinate]'
E:\Coding\CP\solid-octo-engine\DataStructures and Algorithms\Queue\QueueImplementationUsingLL.cpp:101:24:   required from here
E:\Coding\CP\solid-octo-engine\DataStructures and Algorithms\Queue\QueueImplementationUsingLL.cpp:14:2: error: no matching function for call to 'coordinate::coordinate()'
  {
  ^
E:\Coding\CP\solid-octo-engine\DataStructures and Algorithms\Queue\QueueImplementationUsingLL.cpp:88:2: note: candidate: 'coordinate::coordinate(int, int)'
  coordinate(int a,int b)
  ^~~~~~~~~~
E:\Coding\CP\solid-octo-engine\DataStructures and Algorithms\Queue\QueueImplementationUsingLL.cpp:88:2: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
E:\Coding\CP\solid-octo-engine\DataStructures and Algorithms\Queue\QueueImplementationUsingLL.cpp:83:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr coordinate::coordinate(const coordinate&)'
 class coordinate
       ^~~~~~~~~~
E:\Coding\CP\solid-octo-engine\DataStructures and Algorithms\Queue\QueueImplementationUsingLL.cpp:83:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
E:\Coding\CP\solid-octo-engine\DataStructures and Algorithms\Queue\QueueImplementationUsingLL.cpp:83:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr coordinate::coordinate(coordinate&&)'
E:\Coding\CP\solid-octo-engine\DataStructures and Algorithms\Queue\QueueImplementationUsingLL.cpp:83:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: You may want to throw an exception instead.

Comment: Odd mix of C++17 and C++03. My guess is that the C++17 CTAD is accidental.

Comment: An alternate way to deal with this is create a `coordinate` that has an invalid state that can be tested (maybe add a `bool isValid() const;`and return that instead. Then the client code would have to test if the object is valid every time it retrieves it from your code before using. There is also std::optional which could be used similarly.

Comment: A queue from scratch is a bit interesting. It's usually better to have a queue wrap something else like a dynamic array or linked list. With that said, the Standard Library uses a deque (double-ended queue) as a base for `std::queue` and `std::stack`.

Comment: If you are just implementing this for yourself for learning purposes, I would advice you to do it efficiently with ```std::vector``` and remember the front position but not deleting them. This will get you much more familiar with good c++ programming than implementing your own queue from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two smaller issues prevent your code from compiling:

> ```
> return NULL;
> ```

You shouldn't be using `NULL`. Not at all. Your `front` returns a `T`, ie an object, but `coordinates` has no consturctor that lets you construct a `coordinate` from `NULL`. A fix that makes your code compile (in conjunction with the next point) is to return a default constructed element:

```
T front()
{
    if(empty())
    {
        return {};
    }
// ...
```

However, you should reconsider what you want to do when there is no `front`. As you declared the method to return a `T` you cannot return no `T`. Maybe `std::optional` is an option.

Next, your `coordinate` has no default constructor, but you try to default construct one in some places (also in my fix above). If you change the constructor to

```
coordinate(int a = 0,int b = 0)
{
    this->x = a;
    this->y = b;
}
```

Then that is a default constructor (can be called without arguments) and the code compiles without error: https://godbolt.org/z/8E97ca.

However, you should change at least one thing: The body of the constructor is not the place to initialize members! Members are initialized before the body of the constructor runs. Change it to:

```
node(T x) : value(x), next(nullptr)
{
}
```

and similar

```
coordinate(int a = 0,int b = 0) : x(a), y(b) 
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This very elaborate error tells you that there is no way to convert `NULL` (which is int value `0`) to `coordinate` in

```
T front()
{
    if(empty())
    {
        return NULL; //here
    }
    else
    {
        return start->value;
    }
}
```

And that's true, there is no way to convert. You need to either throw an exception if `empty()` returns `true` or let users of your queue embrace the Undefined Behaviour and do nothing to prevent such issue.

```
T front()
{
    return start->value; //UB if empty, but that's users' fault
}
```